# A car travels 78 kilometers at an average speed

Tags: homework-and-exercises

A car travels 78 kilometers at an average speed of 34 km/h and then travels 78 kilometers at an average speed of 75 km/h. The average speed of the car for this trip is (in km/hr):

Comment: Welcome to Physics! Please note that Physics.StackExchange is *not* a homework help site. Please [see this Meta post on asking homework-like questions](http://meta.physics.stackexchange.com/questions/714/) and [this Meta post for "check my work" problems](http://meta.physics.stackexchange.com/questions/6093)

Answer (score 1):

**Hint**

Use :
$$\mathrm{velocity} = \frac{\mathrm{distance}}{\mathrm{time}},~~ \mathrm{time} = \frac{\mathrm{distance}}{\mathrm{velocity}}$$

Time for first $78~\mathrm{km}$ is $\frac{78}{34}~\mathrm{hrs}$. 
Then you calculate time needed for second $78~\mathrm{km}$.

Finally you calculate the total time and the total distance and you will get the average speed.